# Gephi 0.9.1 does not display edge arrows whith curved edges

Tags: graph, gephi

I have a very simple network consisting of four nodes and seven directed edges.

When I look in the "Preview"-mode at the network with straight edges, the arrows are shown. But if there are edges back and forth between two nodes, only one edge is displayed and information of the edge weight is lost.

Here my example:
[image]

If I set the edges to be curved I can see all the edges, but the arrows are gone. See:

[image]

Thus, my question: Is there a way to show edge arrows when the edges are curved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1680) or "feature" if you prefer...